# Nominatim library gives error for Connection pooling occasionally

Tags: python-3.6, connection-pooling, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I am using Nominatim with geoPy for reverse-geocoding . It does work but sometimes gives error for connection pool . How do i solve that ?

Error : `geopy.exc.GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /reverse?lat=16.5268&lon=80.6477&format=json&accept-language=en&addressdetails=1 (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=1)",))`

Code is :

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent=HOST_NAME)
reverse = RateLimiter(geolocator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=1)
coord=str(lat)+","+str(lng)
location=reverse(coord,language='en',exactly_one=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi  Answering my own question , just added a default_timeout of

`export PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100`

worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

```
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geopy.geocoders.options.default_user_agent = "my"`enter code here`
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my")
reverse = RateLimiter(geolocator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=1)
coord=str(lat)+","+str(lng)
location=reverse(coord,language='en',exactly_one=True)`enter code here
```

Comment: This one has solved my problem. Thanks